# PNG File Not Successfully Copying Over From Android Studio To Python

Tags: python, android, kotlin

I am creating an app using Kotlin and Android Studio. With this app, the user can snap a photo with the android camera and I am trying to send that photo to the backend where I will process it using python. The part in Kotlin where I am creating and sending the png file looks like:

```
val con = requireActivity().contentResolver
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(con, image_uri)

val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
val byteArray: ByteArray = stream.toByteArray()
val requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), byteArray)

    submitLocation(
        user,
        locationName.text.toString(),
        address.text.toString(),
        requestBody
    )
```

I can tell that something is making its way to the Python backend but I can not seem to do anything to actually get a legit Png opened up. The python code looks like:

```
form = request.form
if 'image' in form.keys():
    imgdata = bytearray(str(form['image']).encode())

    f = open('myimage.PNG', 'wb')
    f.write(imgdata)
    f.close()
```

Something I am noticing is the array in Kotlin is often near 50,000 elements whereas whenever I get it into Python it is usually somewhere just below 30,000 elements. If I run the code show above it creates a file named 'myimage.png' but if I try to open it on my Mac, I get a warning saying:

```
"The file "myimage.png" could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize."
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here `str(form['image']).encode()` ? whats wrong with writing `form['image']` directly to disk? also, why use `application/octet-stream` and not `image/png` ?

Comment: I initially tried just writing ```form['image']``` but I get an error in python: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: I then tried writing ```bytearray(form['image'])``` and python complains:  TypeError: string argument without an encoding

Comment: sorry I edited the first comment to include the error

Comment: string? is your data b64 encoded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244187/discussion-between-nullman-and-tyler).

Comment: I am not sure. I am snapping the photo in an Android Studio Emulator, taking the Uri and making a bitmap, and then using that bitmap to create the RequestBody. I don't know of any encoding going on up until the moment I user the .encode() function in python

Comment: did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: Hey @Nullman, I tried all the recommendations that you gave me and nothing seemed to work. I am starting to wonder if the data I am receiving from Android Studio is even any good. Python does not seem to want anything to do with it so far.

Comment: try looking at `form['image']`, maybe print the first 10 characters and see what it looks like. if you cant tell add it here and ill try and help you

Comment: Sorry for long delay, Stack Overflow doesn't send me notifications. I am not on the machine right now that has the program. I will run that as soon as I can and update the answer in here. Thanks a ton for being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. you will need to convert your bytes by
[x if x >=0 else 256 + x  if x in bytes_in_ints], and you can check your conversion is working by looking at first four bytes. it should be [137, 80, 78, 71]